# angularJS dependent dropdown

Tags: angularjs

I am using angularJS. I have to arrays as below to populate two dropdowns. One is Class and another is Section.
One class can have multiple sections.
**I want base on class select from class dropdown, section dropdown show ONLY section of that class only.**

```
classes = [
    {"academicYear":"2015","classId":"1","classStd":"Prep-2015"},
    {"academicYear":"2015","classId":"3","classStd":"NUR"},
    {"academicYear":"2015","classId":"4","classStd":"STD-1"}
    ]

section =  [
    {"academicYear":"2015","sectionId":"5","classId":"1","section":"A","sectionName":"ROSE"},
    {"academicYear":"2015","sectionId":"6","classId":"1","section":"B","sectionName":"RED"},
    {"academicYear":"2015","sectionId":"7","classId":"1","section":"C","sectionName":"green"},
    {"academicYear":"2015","sectionId":"8","classId":"3","section":"A","sectionName":"ROME"},
    {"academicYear":"2015","sectionId":"9","classId":"3","section":"B","sectionName":"PARIS"}
    ]



Class DropDown



    <div class="col-md-4">
            <select class="form-control" id="inputclassId" name="inputclassId"
                    ng-model='subjectAllocation.classId'
                    ng-options="classList.classId as classList.classStd for classList in vm.classList"
                    required >
            </select>
        </div>

    Section DropDown



        <div class="col-md-4">
            <select class="form-control" id="inputsectionId" name="inputsectionId"
                    ng-model='subjectAllocation.sectionId'
                    ng-options="sectionList.sectionId as sectionList.sectionName for sectionList in vm.sections"
                    required >
            </select>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the ngRepeat, use a filter to only display the sections corresponding to the proper classId.

```
 <select class="form-control" id="inputclassId" name="inputclassId"
                    ng-model='subjectAllocation.classId'
                    ng-options="classList.classId as classList.classStd for classList in vm.classList"
                    required >
            </select>

<div class="col-md-4">
            <select class="form-control" id="inputsectionId" name="inputsectionId"
                    ng-model='subjectAllocation.sectionId'
                    ng-options="sectionList.sectionId as sectionList.sectionName for sectionList in vm.sections | filter:{classId:subjectAllocation.classId}"
                    required >
            </select>
        </div>
```

You may also want to ensure that someone doesn't input a class, then a section, then change their class. You can do this using a watch statement.

```
$scope.$watch('subjectAllocation.classId', function(newval, oldval){
    if(newval != oldval) {
        delete $scope.subjectAllocation.sectionId;
    }
});
```